# Uso de várias condicionais numa query de SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, operadores, operador-lógico

Estou com dúvida em como realisar uma query com condicionais diferentes.
A query se trata de uma validação de login, preciso verificar se o dado contido no input usuario é igual ao username ou ao email ou ao cpf e se a senha está correta.
Usei esta query

```sql
SELECT * FROM student WHERE username = '$user' OR email = '$user' OR cpf = '$user' AND password = '$password'
```

Porém quando a senha está incorreta ele ainda retorna o usuário. Se eu pudesse separar por parênteses como em operações matemáticas, precisaria de algo assim para dar certo

```sql
SELECT * FROM student WHERE (username = '$user' OR email = '$user' OR cpf = '$user') AND password = '$password'
```

alguém sabe como fazer esta checagem?

Comment: E qual foi o resultado de seus testes? Acho conveniente você estudar sobre SQL Injection.

Comment: A parte da senha é q ainda me preocupa mais... O input ainda pode ter um sanitize.

Comment: A dúvida é sobre "logon" ou ("ands" & "ors") ? Contra o que está se comparado a password ? Guardada sem criptografia ?

Answer (score 0):

Não há nada de errado em ter `(` `)` nas queries à base de dados e os mesmos funcionam como em qualquer outra lugar, mesmo como na matemática que aprendemos na escola.

Como não há exemplos de dados da base de dados e de inputs, não há como ter qualquer certeza, mas a falta de dados pode se explicar pelo uso da igualdade na comparação de strings. Quando se compara dados de texto da base de dados raras são as vezes que se deve usar o `=` em detrimento do `LIKE`.

Outras razões para a query não retornar dados também podem ser divergências em collations e maiúsculas/minúsculas. É necessário verificar os dados e o input, bem como o que se deseja retornar em cada caso.

Agora, o que parece mesmo estar acontecendo é que a query está buscando por `username` = `$user` e não o VALOR de `$user`. É necessário alterar a string para usar string interpolation, por exemplo. A linguagem onde a query é feita não está na pergunta, mas poderia dar o exemplo com PHP (já com a alteração para uso do `LIKE`):

```php
var $query = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE (username LIKE '". $user ."' OR email LIKE '". $user ."' OR cpf LIKE '". $user ."') AND password LIKE '". $password ."'";
```

O grande problema do apresentado na pergunta, como exposto nos comentários é mesmo a forma como s é feita a query, permitindo, por exemplo, fazer `SQL Injection`. Deve-se trocar a query por `prepared statements`.

Outro problema também parece ser em relação às senhas, que pelo apresentado, aparentam estar armazenadas na base de dados. Nunca devemos armazenar senhas "abertas" na base de dados. Deve-se usar mecanismos fortes de criptografia (`SHA256` ou `SHA512`, por exemplo) e armazenar o resultado dessas funções. Ao fazer isso, será preciso trocar a sua query para antes buscar o `student`, sem olhar para a senha, usando somente a parte apresentada entre parêntesis (`username LIKE '". $user ."' OR email LIKE '". $user ."' OR cpf LIKE '". $user ."'`) e em seguida usa-se uma função de comparação de strings criptografadas para comparar o input do usuário *já criptografado* com o que está na base de dados.

Mais uma vez usando PHP como exemplo:

```php
$hashedPasswordFromPost = hash('sha512', $_POST['password']); // SENHA UTILIZADA NO FORM
$hashedPasswordFromDB = ...; // SENHA QUE ESTÁ NO BD

if (password_verify($hashedPasswordFromPost, $hashedPasswordFromDB)) {
  // Usuário válido
} else {
 // Usuário ou senha incorreto
}
```